Rails background job doesn't write to file
I have a background job that should print some content to a file or create a new file if the file doesn't exist yet. I use this snippet:
File.open(File.join(Dir.pwd, 'app/views/stuff', "index.html.erb"), "w") do |f|
     f.write("Here comes the content")
end

The snippet works fine when I put it into a controller. But when I run it inside a background job the job completes "successfully" but the file is not updated or created.
What's the problem? Is a background job not allowed to write to the file system?

Are there are any errors?  Are you sure it is being called by the background job? Do you have any logging?

Logger and dashboard say job is completed successfully.

there is no way to know what is going on in your system without more information

My bet is the current directory (Dir.pwd) is not the same in both cases - a little logging would go a long way

Why on earth do you want to do this? I can't see any valid scenario where you would want to modify your application code at runtime from a background job. The only thing I can think of is that you're not separating your code from the content/data it supposed to operate on.
